# Bash nested double-quoting word split inconsistency

Tags: bash, nested, double-quotes, quoting

I've been messing around with bash quoting and have noticed the following oddity which seems to show inconsistent behaviour and was wondering if anyone can explain what is going on?:

If I do a test with cp using nested double quotes:

```
$ filename="file name"
$ cp "/a/path/to/"${filename}"" /tmp
+ cp /a/path/to/file name /tmp
cp: cannot stat '/a/path/to/file': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'name': No such file or directory
```

Ok so it's splitting the words - seems reasonable if you consider the " character as a toggle on/off for quoting and read left-to-right.

Interestingly the word-splitting here works as expected:

```
$ cp "/a/path/to/${filename}" /tmp
+ cp '/a/path/to/file name /tmp'
cp: cannot stat '/a/path/to/file name': No such file or directory
```

OK, so why doesn't a variable assignment behave the same way?
e.g.

```
pathname="/a/path/to/"${filename}"" 

surely should be the same as typing:

$ pathname=/a/path/to/file name
+ pathname=/a/path/to/file
+ name
-bash: name: command not found
```

but what actually happens is:

```
$ pathname="/a/path/to/"${filename}""
+ pathname='/a/path/to/file name'
```

It works fine?!

Quoting behaviour seems inconsistent between variables and commmands.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way BASH does the expansion across the line.

If you read [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/grammar/parser_exec) you will see that the first step is setting aside anything that looks like `word=word` and then the rest of the line is parsed.

Apparently your

```
$ pathname="/a/path/to/"${filename}""
```

is interpreted simply as `word=word` and saved for processing later on in the expansion process.  When it gets to that later step it expands the contained variable and does the assignment and you end up with *voila* a perceived inconsistency.

Comment: The [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_03) is a good read also.